# The Michael line is not Lindelöf

Tags: general-topology

> Prove that the Michael line is not Lindelöf.

The *Michael line* is the space with underlying set $\mathbb{R}$ having the  topology generated by the base $$\mathcal{B} = \{ U \subseteq \mathbb{R} : U\text{ is open in the usual metric topology on }\mathbb{R} \} \cup \{ \{ x \} : x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \}.$$

We know the Michael line is Hausdorff, but why isn't it Lindelöf?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Find an uncountable closed discrete subset of the Michael line. The result proved in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/265078/12042) may be useful.

Comment: will uncountable Euclidean closed set consisting entirely of irrational numbers work

Comment: @Ramu: Yes, it will, and you can use the linked answer to see why there is one.

Comment: thanks. can u give me hint on proving that int of metric space = int of topology. i m confused as int is just a point in metric where as it is a union of points in topology

Comment: @Ramu: Do you mean *interior*? The interior of a set $A$ in a metric space $\langle X,d\rangle$ is a set: it’s $$\left\{x\in U:\exists r>0\big(B_d(x,r)\subseteq A\big)\right\}\;,$$ where $B_d(x,r)$ is the open $d$-ball of radius $r$ and centre $x$.