# Open Measurable Sets Containing All Rational Numbers

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

So I am trying to figure out a proof for the following statement, but I'm not really sure how to go about it.  The statement is: "Show that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists an open set *G* in $\mathbb{R}$ which contains all of the rational numbers but $m(G)<\epsilon$."  How can it be true that the open set *G* contains all of the rational numbers but has an arbitrarily small measure?

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/195319/12042) to a related earlier question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To elaborate on other answers, let $\{r_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an enumeration of all rational numbers. This is possible because $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable. For each number $r_n$, pick the open interval $(r_n - 2^{-n-1} \epsilon, r_n + 2^{-n-1} \epsilon)$. Each open interval is an open set. The union of all such intervals is also open. The measure of each interval is its length $2^{-n} \epsilon$. If $G$ is the union of these intervals, we have:

$$
m(G) \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n} \epsilon = \epsilon
$$

Where the sum above is a geometric series.

Answer (score 4):

The rationals are denumerable.  Enumerate them and then choose an interval of length less than $\epsilon/2^n$ for $n\ge 1$.  Let $G$ be the union of these intervals. It has measure less than $\epsilon$ and contains all rationals.

Comment: You can do this for any countable set.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  if you order the rationals, you can put an interval around each successive one and take the union for your set.  If the intervals decrease in length quickly enough....