# To show some set is positive Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $P$ be a set of positive Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $O$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $E=P\cap O$ is a set of zero Lebesgue measure. Can we conclude that $P\setminus \overline{E}$ is a set of positive Lebesgue measure?

Comment: We cannot, it may even be empty. Try constructing such a situation starting from an appropriate $E$.

Comment: Do need to consider $P$ to be a fat Cantor set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Let $n=1$. Let $O$ be an open set which contains the rationals and has finite measure. Let $P=(\mathbb{R}\setminus O)\cup\mathbb{Q}$. Then $E=\mathbb{Q}$ so $P\setminus \overline{E}=\emptyset$.

Comment: An open set which contains all rationals? I can't imagine one.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201410/open-measurable-sets-containing-all-rational-numbers

Comment: @Mathemajician The rationals are **countable**.