# An example of an open set of real numbers containing the set of rational and having complementary non-countable.

Tags: real-analysis

An example of an open set of real numbers containing the set of rational and having complementary non-countable.

I can not think of any set that satisfies this condition.

Comment: Se [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/195319/32441) for a previous answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix an enumeration $\{r_k\}_{k \in \Bbb{N}}$ of $\Bbb{Q}$ and let $O_k = (r_k - \frac{1}{2^k}, r_k + \frac{1}{2^k})$. Consider $O = \bigcup_k O_k$. Do you see why $O$ contains every rational number, while also having very large complement?

Comment: sorry, but I can not see that the complement of $O$ is great.

Comment: @Henfe Each interval $O_k$ has length $1/2^{k -1}$. Adding up all the lengths gives a finite number (in fact, $2@), since it's a geometric series.